# Trading view equatio. Creation

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I have some changes in my old equation . I mentioned it on comments section. Please read it. I want to create an indicator on Trading View. With below equation.

```
If Close>open, add close with 
 previous close
If close<open, minus close 
 from previous close
If close =open   and  
 close>previous close, add close 
 with previous close
If close =open and  close<previous 
 close, minus close from previous 
 close
If close=open and close=previous 
 close,Add zero with previous close
```

Also add a middle line zero line
I am attaching my old equation photo.
[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

```
// @version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

var float a = na

if (close > open)
    a := close + close[1]
else if (close < open)
    a := close - close[1]
else if (close == open and close > close[1])
    a := close + close[1]
else if (close == open and close < close[1])
    a := close - close[1]
else if (close == open and close == close[1])
    a := close[1]
else
    a := 0

plot(a)
```

Comment: Note "close" refers to current price, close[1] to yesterday's and close[2] to the day before